# TypeScript: Turn a Container<Maybe<unknown>> into Maybe<Container<unknown>>

Tags: typescript

Using Typescipt 4.x.x

I wrote some code to implement the Maybe/Option type commonly used in other languages Elm/Rust/Haskell.

I wanted to write a generic function that could take a mapped type

```
type MyMappedType<T> = {
    value: T
    name: string
}
```

which has a `Maybe<unknown>` as one of its type parameters eg. `MyMappedType<Maybe<unknown>>` and return a `Maybe<MappedType<unknown>>`.

However I could not find a nice way to describe this, below is my attempt and the `extract` function is the one of interest. It currently just iterates over all the fields, but ideally I could use some typescript smarts to only inspect the field/fields that contain a `Maybe`. Can this be done in a generic way?

example can be run in the TypeScript [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBSBXAzjAPAFQD44BeOAbQDkIA7SjAGwYEMAjB4AwgXQChfQkWHADGtHHBoQYACwCWNAOakKfAeGjwkKONVkLlZbcAgAzSdPlL%20gzQmSoAss0StORFZhxc4AH12WBjYawqYYNCIwcrRwAFbYeEQAFDAAXAF0jCzs7oQAlOnOrrlwAN68cJVwUMAwGFA0FDB8AL7BQvBhEVExALbMYAQANHAASoQphS5uXCOm6ZNw%20CMKACagAPzpNBi9blB5pMSjBXBFM%20NlFVU1dQ0IAHT9YEmmh8xYZ9Oc47xt6h04F1ItFGnIsF5EhM0l9ilxTvBwegEj5ylU4AB6DFLBxwRQYZhQVafQmoKDhKK9VAiGTAEQAa2AqwQECWAGUEBgwBwSTU4MxIgSmIg4ABBKBQFxYa6VW71RriyWIB7gxUuFKHABkmseHCUslIZAAjHANghyah0qZmAwsMA-u07MCemCsHorIouItzrkEXAke6DFd0XL7mrlaqJeqYFqdTAHnrFAaSGQAAxmmAWuBWm12h2O0LhEExcIAd0lg2SMMh8ODN1q8oQ5FT3H5n3w%20dshe6oKBcgYMGAUC9zCmcKI5G4p3wk7rsob92YD1M-cHUCS4MheSeAySZYreU7IU6RZdcHW1sYMGcYAAqjRywNhnAACLQsczIhzBYw5b%20mjrCAWySLs%20yHCQxAviMqzpC%20pwvnO1QLq6kIaqaQJ7g%20FYaoc6SrPmxhwAAwrQMDMAoQ64AAkjQNBDsQZClC0mLYrgAC0CDyJ8SKsMw%20EAk6p69qAmYCngNF0VA77EaR5GSbgPrUbR9H5B%20nAkTQZEUcOEkqWiVQcPANRYFeKhMTKQLQHASSGRQjKIEMABuNoYMArZmHAADyrCxHS8bAJpUByMAWA4fp6KVHI5gbm6gRKEkzkMK5bawjMzA0Ig%20R5OFEUhshFj6NYuWVMxFnFV5Pl%20Q8HxYHIig0EkxlXiMpTkPZ3B4cAl4Dje96Pi8iXJR8qWcOlmUrMpUAQf%20kkjINwB5C0h7om0eV3I08Q4I1IVXoe-yEY4iAaVp8keIxFnzekHbojQzBUukOBBdY-y2U1A4qCJkqREkpSXaoIy3fdcAAOSxHdIXA8xw2HcdcmUYpj0GIQ%20T8GINBYBAHAJhAihJJ9Yk-X95CgwkwPcAD4PpKD4NYJDeSHrwQA)

```
export type Just<T> = [NonNullable<T>]

export const nothing = []

export type Nothing = typeof nothing

export type Maybe<T> = Just<T> | Nothing

export function just<T>(t: NonNullable<T>): Maybe<T> {
    return [t]
}

export function map<T, R>(t: Maybe<T>, f: (t: T, index?: number) => R): Maybe<R> {
    return t.map(f) as Maybe<R>
}

export function isJust<T>(t: Maybe<T>): t is Just<T> {
    // Type guards are runtime checked, so TS tuples are actually Arrays
    return Array.isArray(t) && t.length == 1 ? true : false
}

export function isNothing<T>(t: Maybe<T>): t is Nothing {
    return Array.isArray(t) && t.length == 0? true : false
}


export function unwrap<T>(t: Just<T>) {
    return t[0] as T
}

export function filter<T>(a: Maybe<T>[]): T[] {
    return a.filter(isJust).map(unwrap)
}

export function defaultMapUnwrap<T, D>(t: Maybe<T>, f: (t: T, index?: number) => D, d: D): D {
    return isJust(t) ? f(unwrap(t)) : d
}

type Container<Inner> = {} // <- this is bad
// How do I make this function better?
export function extract<Inner>(t: Container<Maybe<Inner>>): Maybe<Container<Inner>>{
    let result = {}
    for (let [key,value] of Object.entries(t)){
        if (isNothing(value as Maybe<any>)){
            return nothing
        } 
            Object.assign(result, {[key]: defaultMapUnwrap(value as Maybe<any>, inner=> inner, value)})
    }
    return just(result)
}
```

Comment: You can just use `filter` with predicate as a typeguard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It currently just iterates over all the fields, but ideally I could use some typescript smarts to only inspect the field/fields that contain a Maybe. Can this be done in a generic way?

Your generic `Container<T>` type should know which fields can be `T`. In your example, `Container<T>` is just an empty object shape, so what's the point of having a type parameter, or even the type at all?

Additionally, I would recommend using `interface`s rather than `type`s for the definition of object shapes. That will allow other shapes to `extend` from it, ensuring the properties of the extension have the properties of the super. For example:

```
interface Container<T> {
  value: T;
}
interface MyContainer<T> extends Container<T> {
  name: 'bob';
}
const myContainer: MyContainer<'builds'> = {
  name: 'bob',
  value: 'builds',
};
```

Now you know which fields may be `Maybe<T>` for any generic `Container<Maybe<T>>`. If you want to also know which fields can be `Maybe<T>` for a more specific `Container` extension, you will need separate handling for that specific type.
With type-safety in mind: in your example, you just iterate over all of the fields and compare it with `nothing`, but how would the interpreter know that a value is meant to be interpreted as `nothing = []` and not an empty array of data?

If you want to iterate over the keys of a `Container` to find `Maybe<T>` values, it may be helpful to create a `class Maybe<T>`. That way you can check that a value is an `instanceof Maybe`.

Unfortunately, as of TypeScript 4.3.2, there is no sense of a generic parameterized type parameter, so you can't do something like this to get back the same parameterized type that you passed in (along with some code that you may find useful):

```
// NOT A VALID SIGNATURE!!!
function extract<T, A extends Container>(t: A<Maybe<T>>): Maybe<A<T>> {
  return t.value.length === 0
    ? nothing
    : [
        {
          ...t,
          value: t.value[0],
        },
      ];
}
```

###### Aside

I think your definitions of `Just<T>` and `Nothing` are a bit odd. You define them as an single-value array tuple and an empty array tuple, but remove `null` and `undefined` types from your toolbelt with `NonNullable`.

I would instead define them like this to open up more possibilities for your code:

```
type Just<T> = [T];
type Nothing = [];
type Maybe<T> = Just<T> | Nothing;

const x: Maybe<string | undefined> & Nothing = [];
const y: Maybe<string | undefined> & Just<string | undefined> = [undefined];
const z: Maybe<string | undefined> & Just<string | undefined> = ['something else'];
console.log(x.length); // 0
console.log(y.length); // 1
console.log(z.length); // 1
```

Comment: Indeed this cannot be done in a generic way and requires specific implementations for each  `Container` type you have, thank you. In response to your aside, the `Maybe` type is designed to capture the possibility of a missing value in the `Nothing` arm so that if you have a `Just<T>` you know there is a valid value. Using an empty array for the sentinel `Nothing` is nice because `.map()` is defined for both possible types `Just<T>` and `Nothing` and `nothing.map(...) == nothing` Unfortunately structural typing means any sentinel chosen could be a valid value in other contexts.

Comment: Re aside: Right, but I think you can still count `null` and `undefined` as valid values and still have the same handling for missing values.

Comment: Edited my answer to include `class Maybe<T>` when iteratively finding `Maybe` types (class instances) would be a preferred method.

Comment: @ j1mbl3s you have answered my question with "Unfortunately, as of TypeScript 4.3.2, there is no sense of a generic parameterized type parameter, so you can't do something like this to get back the same parameterized type that you passed in", I believe the rest of the answer misinterprets the intent of the `Maybe` type.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things in your code which are less than ideal.

If you put it all into one step, your `Maybe` type is this:

```
export type Maybe<T> = [NonNullable<T>] | []
```

Your `isJust` and `isNothing` functions do not need to check `Array.isArray(t)` because `t` which is `Maybe<T>` is *always* an array.  You can also remove the ternary and just return the `boolean` from the comparison.

```
export function isJust<T>(t: Maybe<T>): t is Just<T> {
    return t.length === 1;
}

export function isNothing<T>(t: Maybe<T>): t is Nothing {
    return t.length === 0;
}
```

`unwrap` does not need to assert `as T` because `t[0]` is always `T`.

```
export function unwrap<T>(t: Just<T>): T {
    return t[0];
}
```

You generally don't want to broaden a return type.  A `Just<T>` is also a `Maybe<T>` (but not vice-versa).  Your `just` function should return `Just<T>` instead of `Maybe<T>` so that you have the maximum amount of information.

```
export function just<T>(t: NonNullable<T>): Just<T> {
    return [t]
}
```

---

So now we're getting to the `extract` and the `Container`, which seems unfinished because what even is a `Container`?  It's just an empty object with no relation to `<Inner>`.  Your `MyContainer` type makes sense.  Is that what it's supposed to be?

You have an object with a property `value` that is a `Maybe<string>` and a property `name` that is `string`.  If the `value` is a `Nothing` then you return a `Nothing`.  Otherwise you return basically the same object but with the `Maybe<string>` property unwrapped to a `string`.

I think that you are trying to generalize this but I'm not sure the "rules".  Is the `Maybe` property always `value`?  Could multiple properties be `Maybe`?  It's tricky that some properties are `Maybe` and others are not.  But we can work with this.

Let's **use a mapped type to map any `Maybe` property to its unwrapped version**.  The `T` here is the type for the original container object.  If a property is a `Maybe<U>` we replace it with `U`, otherwise it stays the same type.

```
type UnwrappedContainer<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Maybe<infer U> ? U : T[K]
}
```

If you want better automatic type inference, you might consider unwrapping all arrays.  Typescript will not see `['hello']` as `Maybe<string>` unless explicitly told to do so.  That's because it infers the type as an array `string[]` rather than a tuple `[string]`.

```
type UnwrappedContainer<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<infer U> ? U : T[K]
}
```

**The signature that you want for your function is this,** where `C` is a generic type parameter describing the input container.

```
export function extract<C>(t: C): Maybe<UnwrappedContainer<C>>{
```

---

We've come to the implementation.  I'm now seeing why you had the `Array.isArray(t)` check in `isNothing` before.  It's because you were calling the function with variables that *are not* `Maybe<T>` and avoiding Typescript errors by asserting that they *are* in fact `Maybe<T>`.  **You should not assert things that you know to be false.**  The name property `'james'` is one of the object values that you are checking and we know it's not a `Maybe`.

You can do the `Array.isArray` check in the function, but with the way that you are calling it now you would want `isJust` and `isNothing` to check `unknown` values and not just values which are already known to be `Maybe`.  The `T` doesn't matter in the case of `isNothing` so that one is simple.

```
export function isNothing(t: unknown): t is Nothing {
    return Array.isArray(t) && t.length === 0;
}
```

With `isJust` we have to infer the `T` from an `unknown`.  I am making the generic here refer to the whole input.  If provided with `[string]` the `T` would be `[string]` rather than `string`.  This has gotten stupidly complicated but I think it's accurate.

```
export function isJust<T>(t: T): t is T & Just<T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never> {
    return Array.isArray(t) && t.length === 1;
}
```

It's a lot easier if you do the `Array.isArray` check outside of this function and you're just validating the length.

```
export function isJust<T>(t: T[]): t is Just<T> {
    return t.length === 1;
}
```

I'm not seeing the need to use `defaultMapUnwrap` in `extract` because you aren't mapping anything (`inner => inner`) and you've already validated that `value` isn't empty, so there's no need for a default.

```
export function extract<C>(t: C): Maybe<UnwrappedContainer<C>>{
    const result = {} as UnwrappedContainer<C>;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(t)) {
        if ( Array.isArray(value) ) {
            // If there are any Nothing properties then the whole function returns []
            if ( isNothing(value) ) {
                return nothing;
            }
            // Unwrap non-empty arrays
            result[key as keyof C] = value[0];
        }
        // properties which are not arrays just get returned as-is
        else {
            result[key as keyof C] = value;
        }
    }
    return just(result);
}
```

My implementation isn't actually checking anywhere that `value.length === 1`, just that it's greater than `0`.  We map an object such that if it has any `array` properties then we replace the array with its first element.  If any of those arrays are empty then the entire function returns `[]`.

I guess the only thing I'm not covering is the issue of `NonNullable` and what happens if your array is `[null]`.  You should probably check that, but at this point I've written enough so I'll leave that to you!

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mbk48W)

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy response, the simplification of `isJust` and `isNothing` is something I should have picked up on, the conditional type is certainly an improvement as well. My decision to return a `Maybe` from the `just` function was an attempt at a kind of encapsulation where the inner value could only be manipulated with `map` or extracted with `unwrap` or `defaultMapUnwrap`, However I now realize this is inconsistent with the `nothing` value. In terms of my original question, it seems the answer is "No, there is no way to use TS's type system to only inspect the `Maybe` fields".

Comment: Yeah Typescript types don’t exist at runtime so what you are trying to do won’t work with approach that you have.  Your current Maybe type won’t limit how you can interact with the Maybe values because a Maybe is just a specific type of array.  It still has all of the array prototype methods.  You could define a Maybe differently as an object with certain methods attached to it.  You can use a class as suggested by @j1mbl3s and you can make the actual value a private property such that you can only access it through a method.

Comment: Clearly TS's knows the information I want to use, there is just no way to get at it (even at compile time). It would be great if there was a way! In regards to using a class with attached methods, In my experience it can create problems with serialization, how do you send a method in JSON (rhetorical)? This way if a client is written in JS then apart from parsing, there is no additional processing required to reconstruct the data.

Comment: I was also thinking that using `===` in the `isNothing` function to differentiate between an empty array and an actual nothing would be good. But this information also can't be captured in any standard JSON format